# How can I download sent email?

Tags: email

I use a private mail service a relative of mine manages. It uses SquirrelMail. I don't usually use the webmail, instead, I use an e-mail client (Claws Mail) to download the mail using POP3.

Every now and then though, I will use the webmail to send some mail. I want this mail to be downloaded to Claws Mail too. How can I do this?

Comment: The old practice is to CCyourself in emails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

POP3 does not support mail folders and will only download messages from "INBOX".<sup>1</sup>

You will have to switch to IMAP for mail access – it presents the same folder structure as in the server, so you can see exactly the same messages in Claws and SquirrelMail. (If you want to keep a local copy of all messages, Claws can cache them on disk (like any other client), or you can use OfflineIMAP.)

Alternatively, configure SquirrelMail to save your sent mail to Inbox.

---

<sup>1</sup> Gmail is an exception. It doesn't have real folders, and uses a heavily customized POP3 server, which is why it can merge both "INBOX" and "Sent" for POP3.

Comment: SquirrelMail *itself* uses IMAP to access your mail, so if the admin says they don't support IMAP, do not believe them.

Comment: Gmail has IMAP folder structure: Inbox, and other labels are the top level folders; other folders, including *Sent Mail*, are subfolders of `[gmail]` folder. Gmail web application merges mail from *Inbox* and *Sent Items* into one view: the messages you received and the message you sent are actually in different folders.

Comment: @Alexey: True, but they are only displayed as folders because that's how IMAP works. The server side only uses tags.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Lavabit shut down today (permanently), and I thought I had lost all my mail. Your tip about Claws maintaining an IMAP cache on disk just saved my data. Me happy.

Comment: @QuasarDonkey: I heard about the shutdown, but I didn't know they were stupid enough to destroy all data without any notice...

Comment: I don't think they destroyed the data, they just shutdown the mail servers (the data is encrypted AFAIK). You're right though, they should have given notice. At first, they said the servers were down for maintenance (no prior notice given). It's only when I watched the news this morning, I found out what really happened.

Comment: @QuasarDonkey: After some browsing, I [find articles](http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/08/08/two-providers-of-encrypted-e-mail-shut-down/) saying "Gone. Can’t get it back. Nobody can. We thought it was better to take flak from customers than be forced to turn it over." I guess I can understand why.

Comment: Wow. That was a bold move. I guess if every company did that, there'd be no PRISM programme. I'm just glad claws-mail cached everything. Thanks again for that info.